# filter decimal column in phpGrid

Tags: php, phpgrid

I have a mysql database that includes several fields with decimals.

I'm using phpGrid Lite to display results.

I want users to be able to filter these fields with comparisons ("> 1000"). But all I see for filtering is the text filtering search function. How do I filter results that are numbers, please?

PHP:

```
$db= new C_DataGrid("SELECT * from `mytable`", "myID", "myDB");

    // change default caption
$db-> set_caption("");

// set export type
$db -> enable_export('EXCEL');

//hide primary key column
$db-> set_col_hidden("myID");


$db-> set_col_currency("Salary", "$", "", ",", 0, "0.00");


// enable integrated search
$db-> enable_advanced_search(true);

// set height and weight of datagrid

$db->enable_autowidth(true)->enable_autoheight(true);

// increase pagination size to 30
$db-> set_pagesize(35);
$db->enable_debug(true);
$db-> set_row_color('#dbdbdb', 'silver', '#f0f0f0');
$db-> enable_resize(true);

$db-> display();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the field property formatter to "integer" manually.

```
$dg->enable_advanced_search(true);
$dg -> set_col_property("customerNumber",
                        array("formatter"=>"integer",
                            "sorttype"=>"integer"));
```

[image]